# Php use a string as variable name print_r

Tags: php, arrays

my scenario is as follow i have lets say 2 arrays `$array_0` and `$array_1` then i want to print it in a `while` better in a `for`

```
for ($i=0;$i<=1;$i++){
print_r(array($array?));
}
```

how i should declare de array to print_r i try set the string of the name in a variable before but maybe its lacks something

```
for ($i=0;$i<=1;$i++){
$str_array='$array_'.$i;
print_r(array($str_array));
}
```

but that prints something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => $array_0
)
Array
(
    [0] => $array_1
)
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself naming things `$foo_1` and `foo_2` and having problems like this it means that they should be contained in an array, eg: `$foo = [ $foo_1, $foo_2 ];` and then you don't have to do any of this foolishness with variable variables.

Comment: oh i see and then do something like `print_r(array($foo[$i]));` inside of the `for` i like it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for variable variables.

```
$array_0 = ['foo'];
$array_1 = ['bar'];

for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++) {
    print_r(${'array_' . $i}); // Here we "build" the variable name
}
```

Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/PLApU

You can read more about variable variables in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "variable variable" by putting a second dollar sign. Here is an example:

```
$arr_1 = array(1=>'a', 2=>'b');
$arr_2 = array(1=>'c', 2=>'d', 3=>'e');

for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++){
    $arrname = 'arr_'.$i;
    print_r(${$arrname});
}
```

You can use $$arrname instead of ${$arrname}; however I found the latter more clear to understand what's happening.